# Is there a correlation between goalkeeper height and penalty save rate?

Tags: football, statistics, penalty-shot, goalkeeper

A tall goalkeeper can be quite intimidating for a penalty taker. Is there any research or statistics that actually shows that there is a correlation between goalkeeper height and penalty save rate?

Comment: Question: are we talking physical saves - or are you counting a miss as a save?

Comment: Good point @ImClarky. I imagine some penalty takers would attempt to shoot higher (which is risky) if the goalkeeper is tall. Reason being that a taller goalkeeper can cover lower corners better (I think). Although it is very subjective, I personally think that a penalty miss is to some extend a goalkeeper's achievement. So, miss = save (especially, if you consider the intimidation factor that may cause additional stress and different/riskier style of penalty taking).

Comment: I don't think this can be answered with science. There are too many factors and every situation is different, even with the same players taking or saving the penalty.

Comment: @dly, why not? A starting point would be a data source with historical penalty data including the information on result of the penalty shot and goalkeeper name (height info could be accessed automatically from wikipedia). I see this as an interesting task to myself. Also maybe someone else too wants to get their hands dirty with data :)

Comment: @gdrt even if there was enough data it would still be mixed with other values, such as weather & pitch conditions, importance of the match, importance of the penalty, etc. You're talking about intimidation, but a player 2-0 in the lead would be less intimidated than being in the same situation 0-2 behind. That's why I believe it's not possible.

Comment: @dly this is why I was asking for correlation. Correlation doesn't state anything about causes or effects, it just shows relationship between variables.